How to properly adjust front derailleur height when it can sway significantly once the clamp bolt is loosened up?
I'm trying to adjust derailleurs myself, for the first time .)
the model is DEORE XT
following the how-to
https://www.wikihow.com/Adjust-a-Shimano-Front-Derailleur
the very first step - adjusting its position
the problem I have is that once I loosen up the clamp bolt, to be able to move the clamp up-down and rotate it, the clamp can be swayed - and the distance between the biggest chain-ring's teeth and the derailleur's frame varies hugely depending on whether you sway it to one side, or to the other
if I tighten the clamp bolt enough for the clamp to not sway - it won't move up/down! (it actually doesn't move very easily even when clamp is loosened - I have to move it with kinda rotating motion, which is not very convenient, because need to remember to adjust the angle after every height adjustment, but i guess this is how it is)
moreover, the fixed position (when the bolt is tightened) is not one of the max positions when you sway it to one or to the other side while bolt is loosened - it is somewhere in-between!
So it seems like absolutely impossible to adjust it properly - the way I'm doing it, at least :D
I'm sure I'm doing something wrong.
But I cannot find anything like that in the official Shimano manual pdf or various text / video how-tos.
I also checked some other questions/answers about adjusting front derailleurs here, and haven't found anyone mentioning similar problem
Thank you in advance for your help!

Front derailleur adjustments are an acquired skill.   One cynical friend observed that the rise of 1-by transmission setups may be related to how hard FDs are to set up !   One trick is to not slacken bolts completely, just loose-enough to bump around by tapping, and that "perfect is the enemy"
